# Зависает терминал при выполнении команды от sudo

Tags: linux, консоль, sudo

При выполнении команд от супер пользователя (sudo), зависает терминал, примерно, на 5 секунд, после чего запрашивается пароль. С чем это может быть связано и как исправить?
ЦП и оперативная память не исчерпаны, не в ресурсах ПК дело.
На скринах показал две разные команды, не в самих командах проблема. При выполнении **любой команды** от **sudo** зависает терминал

[image: скрин терминала]

[image: 2 скрин терминала]

Comment: Две потенциально возможные причины: а) специально сделано в целях безопасности (ну чтобы не сделать _sudo rm -rf /_), б) время обработки базы пользователей (например, если ваша машина в сети типа домена ActiveDirectory).

Comment: @0andriy нет, это домашний ПК и активдайроктари нет. началось такое недавно, до этого не было.
конфиги я, вроде как, не трогал

Comment: `strace sudo` может прояснить ситуацию.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/38114/292034

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin напишите это в ответе, я отмечу решением :) помогло, спасибо!

Comment: там изложено много разных причин. опишите в ответе свою причину и решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aleksandr Barakin дал хорошую [ссылку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157370/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%82-sudo?noredirect=1#comment2007450_1157370), по итогу я под командой **su** удалил (purge --remove) и снова установил **sudo** (на всякий случай), а также в */etc/hosts* добавил свой хост (его можно узнать, набрав команду **hostname**):

```
127.0.0.1       mx
::1             mx
```

Comment: 1. *удалил (purge --remove) и снова установил sudo (на всякий случай)* — в данном случае действие бессмысленное. 2. ни в коем случае не приводите содержимое `/etc/hosts` к подобному виду. надо не удалять ту, информацию, что в нём уже была, а лишь **добавить** имя, которое вы указали в `/etc/hostname`. образец файла можно увидеть в скрипте `/var/lib/dpkg/info/netbase.postinst`

Comment: или, ещё лучше, в `$ man hosts`